# trouble trying to save in multiple rows in the table in php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows

hi am having this trouble trying to save in multiple rows in the table "notification" with a for of customers table ids but it only save me one row this is my code:

```
  $customers = tep_get_customers();
  $count = 0;
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($customers); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $count ++;
$insert_str_cony .= $customers[$i]['id'];
$split_customers_id = explode("||", $insert_str_cony.'||', -1);
$values .= "('','" . tep_db_input('1') . "', now(), '" . tep_db_input($products_id) . "', '" . tep_db_input($split_customers_id[$count]) . "'),";
$db_values = substr_replace($values, '', -1, 1);
}
              if ($action == 'insert_product') { 
                tep_db_query("insert into notifications (notify_id, prod_notify, notify_added, prod_id, customers_id) values ". $db_values);  
                 } elseif ($action == 'update_product') { 
              tep_db_query("update notifications set prod_notify = '" . tep_db_input('1mod') . "', notify_last_mod = now(), prod_id = '" . $HTTP_GET_VARS['pID'] . "', customers_id = '" . tep_db_input($customers['customers_id']) . "'"); 
          }
```

and this is the function tep_get_customers();

```
  function tep_get_customers() {
   $customers_query = tep_db_query("select distinct customers_id from " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . "");
    while ($customers = tep_db_fetch_array($customers_query)) {
      $customers_array[] = array('id' => '||'.$customers['customers_id']);
    }

    return $customers_array;
  }
```

plase need help!!! thanks!

Comment: echo $db_values and show the result.  Also, provide tep_db_query

Comment: i think problem in for loop end } put it below if condition

Answer (score 2):

That is because Insert + values insert one row in the database . (You can use Insert with a SELECT query to insert multiple rows using Insert command but that's not your case as I can see ).
Therefore you should provide a script containing multiple insert commands (an insert command for each customer) in order to insert multiple rows into the database.

Comment: Ha, i missed that they closed their for loop.  I thought they were still looping.